# Do not fill the width of growable flex containers

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I am building a flexbox container, **the container width is resizable**, each element should fill the container width horizontally and **grow** to fill the space between them, and additionally stack vertically if there are too many elements for the row.

The problem is that when there is a row with a single element it fills the entire width of the container, this is cause the `flex-grow: 1;` rule.

[image]

If I remove the `flex-grow: 1;` rule the elements stop growing and does not fill the space between them.

[image]

What I want is make elements growable to fill the space between them but don´t fill the entire width of the container.

Expected result:
[image]

```css
article{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 800px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
section{
    min-width: 200px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<article>
    <section>1</section>
    <section>2</section>
    <section>3</section>
    <section>4</section>
</article>
```

Comment: Try removing the flex-grow and flex-wrap and change min-width to width: 240px;

Comment: Oh... the result is unexpected: https://jsfiddle.net/stramin/g4Lzuck7/2/ they go outside the container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be better to use css grid instead:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}

article {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  gap: 15px;

  width: 800px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

section {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: ok, this is the solution, but can you please tell my how it works? what is minmax? I don´t understand how it works, but it works!

Comment: if it's too complicated for now you can use "grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr" which will just create 4 columns. minmax() and repeat() are css functions, which helps with grid, I recommend checking out examples here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Answer (score 1):

Use e.g `width: 30%` instead `flex-grow` and width with px:

```css
article{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 800px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
section{
    min-width: 30%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<article>
    <section>1</section>
    <section>2</section>
    <section>3</section>
    <section>4</section>
</article>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need to fill the space between them and the container width is resizable, then when it is 500px the elements are too separated https://jsfiddle.net/stramin/g4Lzuck7/1/

Comment: In this case, you can try: `min-width:28%` for the section.